# How to represent a link in an APA style?

Tags: writing, citation, paragraphs

I was reading more on the `APA` style but somehow I got stuck that how can I represent a link in an `APA` style.

Below are the links I have -

```
http://www.mcdpressoffice.eu/downloads/Economic_footprint_Report_Exec_Summary.pdf

http://userwww.service.emory.edu/~eakharu/Positive%20Effects%20of%20McDonalds.htm

http://www.aboutmcdonalds.com/content/dam/AboutMcDonalds/Investors/Investor%202013/2012%20Annual%20Report%20Final.pdf

http://www.unescap.org/tid/publication/indpub2565_chap1.pdf

http://s3.amazonaws.com/mcdbestof-section-pdfs/2/MCD_072_BOSS_FINAL.pdf


http://www.mcdonalds.co.uk/ukhome/Ourworld/Environment/Energy.html

http://www.powersines.com/var/56/522535-CS%20ComEC%20McDonald's.pdf

http://www.bestofgreenmcdonaldseurope.com/casestudies_detail.php?cat=2

http://www.bestofgreenmcdonaldseurope.com/downloads/Energy_all_case_studies.pdf
```

Can anybody provide an example how can I represent a link in an APA style?

Comment: Suggested migration to [writers.se].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seeks guidance as to how to interpret an arbitrary set of guidelines; it does not allow for other accepted conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the APA Style Blog, there is a reference to representing URLs in [this recent article](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2014/01/timestamps-for-audiovisual-materials-in-apa-style.html):

> Audiovisual materials like videos, podcasts, movies, and television shows can make excellent sources for academic papers. To point the reader of a paper to a specific spot in an audiovisual source—such as when you cite a direct quotation—include a timestamp in the APA Style in-text citation, just as you would include a page number under analogous circumstances for a print source like a book or journal article. This post will show you how.

The article concludes with a recommendation on further references:

> See [Publication Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CPUBEBM)§ 7.07 and the [APA Style Guide to Electronic References](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008674FW8) for more example reference formats.

In summary, the procedure is essentially the same as with other citations. Include a citation at the point in the text and include the url in the references and/or bibliography.

See [all 13 posts categorized "URLs"](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/urls/) on the APA Style Blog related to "URLs"

This page on campusGuides has some (quite a few) *APA Quick Examples* of [Using APA Style Guide to Electronic References (2012)](http://nova.campusguides.com/apa)